# adding multiple capes to /etc/default/capemgr for beaglebone black debian

Tags: beagleboneblack

I am unable to load 2 custom capes on the beaglebone black running the current Debian release.
I tried the procedure described here: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#Loading_custom_capes.

I can load a cape during boot using the capemgr file; however when I put 2 custom capes in this file it  only loads the first cape. How can I load 2 custom capes?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this same problem. I listed `CAPE=` twice with two different overlays and only the second one loaded.

```
CAPE=BB-W1
CAPE=BB-SPI0-01
```

This is beacause `CAPE` variable is change to `BB_SPI0-01` after second line and only this one is loaded

**Solution:** 
Add overlays with comma separated in `CAPE` line as shown below:

```
CAPE=BB-W1,BB-SPI0-01
```

Now it will load both the overlay.